Is a capacitor a memoryless system?
According to my textbook,

A system is said to be memoryless if its output for each value of the independent variable at a given time is dependent on the input at only that same time.

It also gives the example of a capacitor, saying that if we take the current to be the input, then the voltage is dependent on its integral making it a "with memory" system.
If we take the voltage as input, then the current only depends on the derivative of voltage at that particular instant of time only, which should make it a memoryless system.
Is a capacitor a memoryless system or does being a memoryless system depend on the input also?

I'd argue that a capacitor is not a system at all, just a component.


then the current only depends on the derivative of voltage at that particular instant of time only,

You are just trying to shift the memory to the voltage input, rather than the capacitor state. The system still contains memory. Note that if the voltage you apply is not equal to the present capacitor voltage, the derivative will be strongly dependent on the capacitor's state of charge, if you permit the derivative to exist by also assuming some extra components to limit the current. Without those extra components, it's an impulse of charge, dependent on the imposed voltage, and the capacitor's previous voltage.
Generally, we class components that store energy, so capacitors and inductors, as having memory, as they are time dependent.

So being memoryless is property of a system? Also if I look at it from a mathematical point of view, then the derivative can be written in this form
$$
{\displaystyle L=\lim _{h\to 0}{\frac {f(a+h)-f(a)}{h}}}
$$
And so the current will depend on the future value of the voltage making it a system ‘with memory’.
Is this reasoning correct?

@lefty no, you are over-thinking it. Chill. No system is dependent on future values, such a system would be called acausal - which can be simulated in a digital offline system with a suitable delay. 'Memory' depends on storage of past behaviour, whether charge, energy, data, temperature, etc
